# Binary Search- TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a binary search using python, but it seems to have an issue comparing the string within a lists index, to my input string. I've tried adding the input string into its own array, but it caused new problems. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
def SearchStudent():

    data = "studentMockData_AS2.txt"
    students = []

    with open(data, "r") as datafile:
            for line in datafile:
                datum = line.split()
                students.append(datum)
    
    searchId = input('Enter student id: ')

            start = 0
            end = len(students)-1

            while (start <= end):
                midPoint = (start + end) // 2
                if students[midPoint] < searchId:
                    start = students[midPoint] + 1
                elif students[midPoint] > searchId:
                    end = students[midPoint] - 1
                else:
                    print(datum)
                    break
            return -1
```

Here is the error:

```
if students[midPoint] < searchId:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'
```

Comment: `students` is a list of list. so `students[midPoint]` is a list and `searchId` is int. You can't compare them like you are trying to

Comment: You should fix your indentation. Apart from that, `searchId` is the result of a call to `input()`, so it's a string (`str`).  `students[midPoint]` is an element of `students`, and `students` is constructed by appending `datum`, which is created with `line.split()` - so a list. You can't compare a list and a string with `<`, which is exactly what the error already told you.

Comment: Is the first item in each line the student id?  Then you need `students[midPoint][0]`.  Are you sure the data file is sorted?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have a bubble sort function and quick sort function ready, but its my first look at binary search and wanted to wrap my head around that on its own first.

Comment: @Grismar I'm aware of why the error is coming up, but I'm new to/bad at programming and not sure how to fix it. Like I said, I even tried converting the input into its own list so that it was comparing lists just out of desperation because I've been stuck on this for longer than I'd like to admit.

Comment: What's actually inside `students[midPoint]`, according to you? What part of `students[midPoint]` do you actually want to compare to `searchId`? When are `students[midPoint]` and `searchId` a match? How would you access a specific part of a list? If you're stuck, that's probably because you're just looking for a complete solution that happens to solve your problem - programming is about breaking down the problem into smaller problems and solving those, and finally putting the small solutions together into a full solution.

Comment: You're doing a split, so I assume your file has multiple columns.  The important question is, what is the KEY you want to sort and search on?  If it is the first column, then my previous comment has the answer.  Remember that a binary search only works on a sorted list.